# C# Overwriting the previous page in printing

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting

Good day to all,
I have an application that creates a report for daily time record of an employee.
The problem is all of the pages in printpreview dialog were overwritting by every pages that available in printing. how can i possibly solve this kind of issue? The content of page 1 is for page 1, page 2 is for page 2 only and vise versa.
Here is my code for printing:

```
    private void simpleButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            countPage = 0;
            CoolPrintPreviewDialog printPreview = new CoolPrintPreviewDialog();
            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
            printPreview.Document = doc;
            Form p = (Form)printPreview;
            p.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            p.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= countEmployee; i++)
            {
                Font fontName = new Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
                Font fontPosition = new Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
                Brush colorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

                e.Graphics.DrawString(empName, fontName, colorBrush, new Point(80, 120));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(empPosition, fontPosition, colorBrush, new Point(80, 140));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(empId, fontPosition, colorBrush, new Point(680, 120));
                DataManipulation.PrintSelectEmployeeByMonth(i, e, comboBoxMonth, comboBoxYear, comboBoxDayFrom, comboBoxDayTo);
                countPage++;
                MessageBox.Show(countPage.ToString());
            }
            if (countPage <= countEmployee)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PrintPage` event is raised once for each page; your `for` loop suggests that you are trying to print all the pages whenever the event is raised.

You need to remove the `for` loop and promote the index variable `i` to an instance-level variable that you can use to track the current page number.

The remainder of your code appears to be correct; you must keep requesting more pages until the event has been fired `countEmployee` times.